# Connecting to an external API with Angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax

I'm trying to connect to the Expedia Api. With this they have an api key and id.

I was using jsonp with this but there is a bug in there causing problems. The other thing is my api key is exposed in the javascript.

So now I have to find another way. I am now requesting json but of course I can't get cross domain with it so I have found a php proxy. My app is now reliant on php (this is ok though). When I access the php proxy I now get authentication errors. I have tried a different endpoint on a different site and the script works.

So therefore I cannot access this API.

There seems to be very little information, tutorials and scripts out there on how to make an api cross site, php proxies or authentication. I thought with the amount of sites now reliant on this type of technology there might be something.

How can I make a php proxy and return this data back to angular?
How can I safely hide my api key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have all of your API keys etc in a PHP file on your server.  In that PHP file you need to curl to the API.  Then have your PHP script return a json_encode() of whatever their API returns.  That way no one sees your API deets.

Comment: Ok that makes sense..How can I complete the round trip by getting it back to Angular?

Comment: $http.post('/url/to/your/script.php', data)
.then(function(s,r){
    console.log(r.data);
});

r.data will contain the response from your php script (which will echo out the response from the API)

Comment: Great thanks got that now. But my php response is now blank or it contains html. How can I return the json object now from the php file? it outputs as a variable $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

Comment: $response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;